# Hiding a panel in blender

Tags: interface, panel

I just started using blender. When I start using a new software / tool, I usually hide panels that I don't need and I show them back when I need them. In that case, I saw a panel at the top right (Hierarchy) which I wanted to keep. I have no idea what i did but i have like 7 duplicated panels...

Here it is...:
[image]

The top right panel is really weird and i have no idea how to remove them...

Comment: Blender does have a manual online, It can save you some headaches and a lot of time. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/areas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can close windows by taking the diagonal 3 lines in the bottom left-hand corner and dragging it up or down to collapse it. In the viewport create a new window by dragging left on the 3 lines in the top right-hand corner, but collapse by dragging right on the same lines.

Hope this helps! :)